# Issue on Putting 4 Divs Exactly on Top of Each Other

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Bootstrap 3 I have a a mark up like below:

```
<!-- Start of Container-->
<div class="container">
    <!-- Start of well-->
    <div class="well">
        <div id="wrapper" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6">
            <div id="layer3" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"></div>
            <div id="layer2" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"><img src="http://localhost/bg_sh.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" /></div>
            <div id="layer1" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"><img src="http://localhost/MapNAs.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" /></div>
            <div id="canvas" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- End of well-->
</div>
<!-- End of Container-->
```

Can you please let me know how I can order the layer3, layer2, layer1, and canvas divs overlay EXACTLY on top of each other

Comment: How do you expect on each device on mobile , tablet , and desktop ? please clarify ?

Comment: Hi Shibin Ragh, Thanks for reply, not really sure what do you mean?! but I like to have this more on Desktop and Tablest

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8A592/1/embedded/result/)

see working area [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8A592/1/)

```
<!-- Start of Container-->
<div class="container">

  <div id="wrapper" class="row">
    <div id="layer3" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">#layer3</div>
    <div id="layer2" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">#layer2</div>
    <div id="layer1" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">#layer1</div>
    <div id="canvas" class="col-sm-6 col-md-12">canvas</div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End of Container-->
```

[More info here about bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

Comment: I am afraid! but this is not what I was expecting! what I need to have is nesting divs exactly on TOP of each other not vertically but in  Z- index direction. like setting all in Wrapper to have top:0;

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<div id="layer3" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 4;position: absolute; top: 0;"></div>
<div id="layer2" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 3;position: absolute; top: 0;"><img src="http://localhost/bg_sh.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" /></div>
<div id="layer1" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 2;position: absolute; top: 0;"><img src="http://localhost/MapNAs.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Responsive image" /></div>
<div id="canvas" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12" style="z-index: 1;position: absolute; top: 0;"></div>
```